How to simplify input to a table with many columns?
While preparing a table on musical modes I came accross this situation:

entering the 7 pitches as one column looks bad after compile, once accidentals occur
finally I had to provide 7 columns instead of one
though this is possible to do I wonder if it couldn't be done better
like passing one argument to a macro, which creates all those & for the table


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{musicography}   % nicer accidentals

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrr}
  \toprule
    Ionian      & 1 &2 &3   &4   &5&6 &7 \\
    Dorian      & 1 &2 &\fl3&   4& 5 &6 &\fl7 \\
    \dots\\
  \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}

\end{document}


You can do better.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{musicography}   % nicer accidentals

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{modes}{O{27mm}}
 {% #1 = first col width
  \begin{tabular}{@{} w{l}{#1} *{7}{w{r}{1em}} @{}}
  \toprule
 }
 {
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
 }

\tl_new:N \l__msspo_mode_scale_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\mode}{mm}
 {% #1 = mode name, #2 = scale
  #1 &
  \tl_set:Nn \l__msspo_mode_scale_tl {#2}
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__msspo_mode_scale_tl { ~ } { & }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__msspo_mode_scale_tl { s } { \sh }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__msspo_mode_scale_tl { b } { \fl }
  \tl_use:N \l__msspo_mode_scale_tl \\
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{modes}
\mode{Ionian}    {1  2  3  4  5  6  7}
\mode{Dorian}    {1  2 b3  4  5  6 b7}
\mode{Phrygian}  {1 b2 b3  4  5 b6 b7}
\midrule
\mode{Lydian}    {1  2  3 s4  5  6  7}
\mode{Mixolydian}{1  2  3  4  5  6 b7}
\mode{Aeolian}   {1  2 b3  4  5 b6 b7}
\mode{Locrian}   {1 b2 b3  4 b5 b6 b7}
\end{modes}

\bigskip

\begin{modes}[15mm]
\mode{Ionian}    {1  2  3  4  5  6  7}
\mode{Dorian}    {1  2 b3  4  5  6 b7}
\mode{Phrygian}  {1 b2 b3  4  5 b6 b7}
\midrule
\mode{Lydian}    {1  2  3 s4  5  6  7}
\mode{Mixolydian}{1  2  3  4  5  6 b7}
\mode{Aeolian}   {1  2 b3  4  5 b6 b7}
\mode{Locrian}   {1 b2 b3  4 b5 b6 b7}
\end{modes}

\end{document}

The input is easier, isn't it?


Nice solution, thank you

Here is one way to do it. Basic idea:

write your pitches as a space separted list
pass it as an argument
substitute all spaces by &

This is done by macro \scale, which calls \StrSubstitute from package xstring. Specifying 0-times means "replacing all". E.g.

calling \scale{1 2 3     4 5 6 7}
creates 1&2&3&4&5&6&7 as needed


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{musicography}   % nicer accidentals
\usepackage{xstring}        % for replace

\newcommand\scale[1]{\StrSubstitute[0]{#1}{ }{&}}
\def\w{27mm} % width of first column

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{p{\w}rrrrrrr}
  \toprule
    Ionian      & \scale{1 2 3      4 5 6 7} \\
    Dorian      & \scale{1 2 \fl3   4 5 6 \fl7} \\
    Phrygian    & \scale{1 \fl2 \fl3 4 5 \fl6 \fl7} \\
    \midrule
    Lydian      & \scale{1 2 3  \sh4 5 6 7} \\
    Mixolydian  & \scale{1 2 3  4 5 6 \fl7} \\
    Aeolian     & \scale{1 2 \fl3 4 5 \fl6 \fl7} \\
    Locrian     & \scale{1 \fl2 \fl3 4 \fl5 \fl6 \fl7} \\
    \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}

\end{document}

